# Active Directory Group members of ISA Server 2006 user set not working on rule

Tags: active-directory, isa-server

When I add a global security group in Active Directory to a user set on ISA Server 2006, the rule using that user set does not take effect for members of the AD group. If I add a single user to the same user set however, it works just fine. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-logon the client (log off Windows and on again) to make sure that AD groups are working properly.